# Semi directProduct and Maximal subgroup in gap

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, computer-algebra-systems

Let $P$ be a quaternion of order 8  and $Q$ a cyclic group of order 9 and $G=[p]Q$, a semidirect product ($P$ is normal in $G$).

Let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$ such that $Q<M$. I want to find $|G : M|$=? in gap.

Comment: Please try and format the question adequately, and more importantly, please complete it!

Comment: Hello Dr.andrea caranti    My question is wrong ?

Comment: @maghsoudmazoochian What are you asking?  I understand $G=PQ$ and $M$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$.  What do you want to know?

Comment: I do not fully understand the meaning of the question, but I have edited your post to use LaTeX as well as to fix your missing question statement.  Here, square brackets on their own line are used to list urls, which is why your remark on what they meant did not appear.

Comment: OK, may I safely assume $Q$ acts non-trivially on $Q$? (To define a semidirect product of $P$ by $Q$, you have to specify a group morphism $Q \to \operatorname{Aut}(P)$.)

Answer (score 3):

There's really no need to use GAP.

There are two possibilities, according to the action of $Q$ on $P$.

If the action is trivial, then $M$ has index 2, and it is the product of $Q$ with one of the (cyclic) subgroups of $P$ of order $4$.

If the action is non-trivial, then $Q$ permutes cyclically the three subgroups of $P$ of order $4$. Then $M$ has index 4, and it is the product of $Q$ with the subgroup of order $2$ of $P$.

Comment: All parts of the problem are clear, but its strange notation. No need to GAP. +1

Comment: Tank you Mr. Andreas Caranti. I need non-trivial action           i read your proof. Can you explain me more ? Please             "Q permutes cyclically the three subgroups of P of order 4. Then M has index 4" ?????